# Seeing either request body/parameters or response in the log

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In the gCloud Log, is there a way to have it log the request or the response from the API?

For example, I notice that using the text recognition API under different light settings for the same text will produce a range of very different results - useful to track these things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by writing to the Stackdriver logs in your code. Stackdriver does not log request or response bodies. This is something your code will need to do. Depending on your program language this is as simple as a print statement.

Comment: ah so it's basically just using it as a storage engine for storing results that are returned and not logging per se?

Comment: If Stackdriver logged requests and results the amount of data would be massive. Remember, Stackdriver is $0.50 per GB. That would be a large bill even for small websites.